how to check slow page loading times
we have a web-based timesheet application, which is often loading very slow on endpoint, to the point where it is barely usable. it is also fairly consistent, it's adding ~10-15 sec loading time.
how could i check what additional process is causing the slowness on the endpoints?
i checked the following:

on the application server with Chromium Edge the loading times are perfect (>100ms)
from a building on the other side of the road (different vlan), but still from a server with Chromium Edge, the loading times still good (>150ms)
from endpoint vlan (same building as application server) the loading times are 15+ sec with both Chromium Edge and Chrome

the firewalls are transparent, there are no errors and there is no service active which would check for any package content. AV and DLP is present on the endpoints, but the issue is present when those are not installed.

[webmasters.se]

Have you tracked the network data via Dev tools?

Could you please provide your Edge and Chrome version when the issue takes place?
